# Grails 2.3.11 ERROR pool.ConnectionPool - Unable to create initial connections of pool

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, datasource

```
2018-04-19 20:57:38,504 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR pool.ConnectionPool  - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host MY-PC, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
```

I get this error three times on startup. I guess this is becuase Grails tries to connect to the database three times upon startup based on [Burt Beckwith's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/160313/burt-beckwith) [No Fluff Just Stuff's Delayed SessionFactory Creation in Grails](https://nofluffjuststuff.com/blog/burt_beckwith/2010/01/delayed_sessionfactory_creation_in_grails)

After the three error prompts, Grails then proceeds to fail on beans creation (transactionManager, transactionManagerPostProcessor, etc).

Based on my understanding, the problem here is the pool creation. I assume Hibernate handles this on Grails. It cannot create the pool since the database is still not online.

To give you a background on the problem, the Grails app is connecting to the database. The database and the Grails server are on different servers. The two servers are restarted concurrently. The Server where the Grails app then proceeds to be online first before the Database Server. This causes the error mentioned since the Grails app tries to connect to the Database which is not online yet.

Is there a way to configure Grails to reconnect to the database server when an error or exception occurs on pool creation? I am currently using MSSQL as my database. I hope you can help me on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your application will not be able to effectively start or run without its backing database, so even if you could reconnect later you would have missed a lot of startup events such as GORM updates.

Since your application won't work until the database is started anyway, could you delay starting the Grails application until after the database is up?  There are multiple approaches for that, and it seems like doing that would give you a much better and cleaner initialization process.

Comment: I think I can delay the Grails application from becoming online. However, since the database is in a different server, it is still not a guarantee that the Grails app can connect to the database even if there is a delay since I am not sure when the database will be online. I am not sure how to approach the delaying. I still need to look into it. Do you have any references that I can look into?

Comment: It will certainly depend on your environment and privileges, but you could use something like `sp_procoption` to execute a stored procedure which in turn uses xp_cmdshell to execute a system command.  Or if everything is running as services (Linux or Windows I guess but I'm certainly more confident about Linux) it should be possible to have one service trigger another (even remotely) post startup.  Or you could just say "database will never take more than 120 seconds" or something like that, and delay that long...simpler, but maybe not as precise.